# How to change a Tkinter label using a Flask API

Tags: python, flask, tkinter, multiprocessing

I have a Flaks API with some endpoints. I use multiprocessing to run it parallel to my Program. Tkinter is started with `window.mainloop()`.
I split all of them into their own classes (I don't know if this affects smth).

I now want to change the text of a label on my tkinter Label. I am using `mylabel.config(text="myText")` and want to call this from my API Endpoint (A function like this:)

```
myEndpoint(self, newStatus:str):
   self.mylabel.config(text=newStatus)
   return newStatus
```

What can I do to change the Label when my Function is run by the API Process?
Thanks for any help

EDIT:
@Bryan Oakley wanted some more information. Here it is:

All functions for the Window are in their own class in another file. My Program imports it, create an Object with all needed parameters (Window Size and so on), and then starts it with:

```
from window import window
w = window(Parameters like Size, ...)
w.start()
```

Start function just changes the fullscreen Parameter and setup some Button actions. Then it calls `self.window.mainloop()`
`window = Tk()` that is setup in my **init**

My Flask API has also its own class in another file and is imported:

```
from api import flaskApi
api = flaskApi(Port, window object, ...)
```

The **init** method of my api class setup Flask add the Endpoint with `app.add_url_rule` to the function `myEndpoint` (see above).

Hope this is all you need, I cant find a solution and are happy about your help. Thanks for any help :)

Comment: does the other process call `myEndpoint`? if so I guess you got some error regarding `tkinter` stuff not being pickleable, correct?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Yeah the other Process can call myEndpoint and change the label text. I will add some more informations to the question. Hope there is a simple way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more and more research I finally found an Answer. To access another Process (here the main Process) from another one (here my Flask API) you need to use a Queue or Pipe ([Queue Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue)).

This Queue (or Pipe) allows you to communicate with another Process. One reads from the Queue (here my Tkinter Window) and one (or more) write into it. Maybe this helps someone else with the same Problem.

Thanks for your help :)